# Microsoft Edge is not opening http://192.168.0.1

Tags: microsoft-edge

I would like to open http://192.168.0.1 address in Microsoft Edge but it's not working... i have domain in hosts file to point to that ip and it's not working too.. any way to access local ips from Microsoft Edge browser?

Loopback option dosen't work here, i tried setting it in about:flags and manually by :
CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe"

Comment: Is this a webserver you have running under http://192.168.0.1? Did you try adding the port? I just tried the same for a webserver running on my local machine which worked perfectly fine. I can access my webserver through http://169.254.234.138:1337 in MS Edge after allowing localhost loopback in about:flags.

Comment: port doesn't help, i have domain in my hosts file, that points to 192.168.0.1 but it doesn't work too, maybe 169/8 class is not added as main local classes in edge. Did you try on 192.168.x.x ?

Comment: Are you trying to hit a router to configure it or something?  
Open the page in IE.  Save the source code down to a local file. 
Then try opening the file in Edge. See what happens.

Guessing here ....  Healy in Tampa

Comment: It will not work.. i am not trying to access any router.

Answer (score 2):

MS Edge lacks privateNetworkClientServer capability. Try playing with how your network connection is setup.

> AppContainer network restrictions are sensitive to your network configuration

Source: [Understanding Enhanced Protected Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you **accessing a webserver on the same host as Edge?**

What finally worked for me was to:

- have the webserver listen on `0.0.0.0` instead of `192.168.0.X` *and*
- allowing the localhost loopback in about:flags

[image: edge about:flags enable loopback]

This was using `Edge 38.14393.0.0`.